# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when plotting multiple charts

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following script:

```
import fxcmpy
import pandas as pd
from pandas import datetime
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import matplotlib
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
from datetime import date
import numpy as np
TOKEN = "hidden "
con = fxcmpy.fxcmpy(access_token=TOKEN, log_level='error')
print(con.get_instruments())
ticker= con.get_instruments()
def convert(ticker):
    return tuple(ticker)
ticker = convert(ticker)
start = datetime.datetime(2008,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime.today()
today = date.today()
data = con.get_candles(ticker, period='D1', start = start, end = end)
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format ='%Y-%m-%d')
```

the variable symbol contains the following list:

```
['EUR/USD', 'USD/JPY', 'GBP/USD', 'USD/CHF', 'EUR/CHF', 'AUD/USD', 'USD/CAD', 'NZD/USD', 'EUR/GBP', 'EUR/JPY', 'GBP/JPY', 'CHF/JPY', 'GBP/CHF', 'EUR/AUD', 'EUR/CAD', 'AUD/CAD', 'AUD/JPY', 'CAD/JPY', 'NZD/JPY', 'GBP/CAD', 'GBP/NZD', 'GBP/AUD', 'AUD/NZD', 'USD/SEK', 'EUR/SEK', 'EUR/NOK', 'USD/NOK', 'USD/MXN', 'AUD/CHF', 'EUR/NZD', 'USD/ZAR', 'USD/HKD', 'ZAR/JPY', 'USD/TRY', 'EUR/TRY', 'NZD/CHF', 'CAD/CHF', 'NZD/CAD', 'TRY/JPY', 'USD/CNH', 'AUS200', 'ESP35', 'FRA40', 'GER30', 'HKG33', 'JPN225', 'NAS100', 'SPX500', 'UK100', 'US30', 'Copper', 'CHN50', 'EUSTX50', 'USDOLLAR', 'US2000', 'USOil', 'UKOil', 'SOYF', 'NGAS', 'WHEATF', 'CORNF', 'Bund', 'XAU/USD', 'XAG/USD', 'EMBasket', 'JPYBasket', 'BTC/USD', 'BCH/USD', 'ETH/USD', 'LTC/USD', 'XRP/USD', 'CryptoMajor', 'ESPORTS', 'BIOTECH', 'CANNABIS', 'FAANG', 'CHN.TECH', 'CHN.ECOMM', 'USEquities']
```

I want to plot subplots eventually but i am not able to pass a list and i get an error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

What can i do to fix this?

--edit 1: 
After updating the code to turn list in to tuple, i am getting the `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why are you getting this error?

Dictionary keys must be hashable objects.

In order for an object to be hashable, it should be an instance of a class that implements `__eq__` and `__hash__` methods.

Objects of list type are not hashable.

*Side note: hashable does not mean immutable in python*

## Solution

You can use tuple instead of list:

```
('EUR/USD', 'USD/JPY', 'GBP/USD', 'USD/CHF', 'EUR/CHF', 'AUD/USD', 'USD/CAD', 'NZD/USD', 'EUR/GBP', 'EUR/JPY', 'GBP/JPY', 'CHF/JPY', 'GBP/CHF', 'EUR/AUD', 'EUR/CAD', 'AUD/CAD', 'AUD/JPY', 'CAD/JPY', 'NZD/JPY', 'GBP/CAD', 'GBP/NZD', 'GBP/AUD', 'AUD/NZD', 'USD/SEK', 'EUR/SEK', 'EUR/NOK', 'USD/NOK', 'USD/MXN', 'AUD/CHF', 'EUR/NZD', 'USD/ZAR', 'USD/HKD', 'ZAR/JPY', 'USD/TRY', 'EUR/TRY', 'NZD/CHF', 'CAD/CHF', 'NZD/CAD', 'TRY/JPY', 'USD/CNH', 'AUS200', 'ESP35', 'FRA40', 'GER30', 'HKG33', 'JPN225', 'NAS100', 'SPX500', 'UK100', 'US30', 'Copper', 'CHN50', 'EUSTX50', 'USDOLLAR', 'US2000', 'USOil', 'UKOil', 'SOYF', 'NGAS', 'WHEATF', 'CORNF', 'Bund', 'XAU/USD', 'XAG/USD', 'EMBasket', 'JPYBasket', 'BTC/USD', 'BCH/USD', 'ETH/USD', 'LTC/USD', 'XRP/USD', 'CryptoMajor', 'ESPORTS', 'BIOTECH', 'CANNABIS', 'FAANG', 'CHN.TECH', 'CHN.ECOMM', 'USEquities')
```

Tuples are sequences, just like lists. The main difference is that tuples are immutable (cannot be modified after initiation).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have converted to tuple as you had suggest(I have updated the code in question). But i am getting `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Comment: use `tuple(list_name)` to convert `list` to `tuple`  in Python